# Sum Values in dataset By Grouping and Loading result to its header row for Trial Balance Sheet

Tags: vb.net

I have created the Data-set by filling values of Assets child accounts and bank balances, AND stock values. Gathered all these values from different tables.

Now problem i want to sum each values in row which has the same parent account number and the result of that want to update in the account number which is parent in the same data-set table.

There are different types of rows. following possibilities could be in the rows.
the row can be parent group account. each group can have different transaction accounts and also group account in child, group account does not have transactions. their value would be only as a sum of their child accounts.

Table is as follows.

```
AccountNo | AccountDepth| ParrentAccountNo|OpeningDebit|
1         |   0         |                 |            | <Main Header
11        |   1         |   1             |            |   <Header Child    
111       |   2         |   11            |10000       |     <Trx   
112       |   2         |   11            |            |   <Header Child
1121      |   3         |   112           | 5000       |     <Trx
1122      |   3         |   112           |15000       |     <Trx   
113       |   2         |   11            |            |   <Hedaer Child
1131      |   3         |   113           |            |   <Header Child
11311     |   4         |   1131          |20000       |      <Trx  
1132      |   3         |   113           |35000       |      <Trx  
12        |   1         |   1             |            |   <Header Child
121       |   2         |   12            |            |     <Header Child
1211      |   3         |   121           |10000       |      <Trx
```

I want to sum each transaction account into header, than sum all header to their header and if their exists any child then its child sum also in header and then all the header to its parent.
Remember that all the values are in DATA-SET Table

Answer (score 0):

I never Got Answer to any of my question from here. Any How I did it my self.
Let me share with you if any one need this too.

```
   Dim currentValue As Integer = 0, Depth As Integer = 0
        For c As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            currentValue = ds.Tables(0).Rows(c).Item("AccountDepth")
            If currentValue > Depth Then Depth = currentValue
        Next

        Dim depthchang As Integer = Depth

        For i = 0 To Depth
            Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0).Clone
            Dim rows() As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Select("AccountDepth = " & depthchang & "")
            Dim row1 As DataRow
            For Each row1 In rows
                dt.ImportRow(row1)
            Next
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                For k = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    If ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("AccountNo") = dt.Rows(k).Item("ParentAccountNo") Then
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("OpeningDebit") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("OpeningDebit") + dt.Rows(k).Item("OpeningDebit")
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("OpeningCredit") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("OpeningCredit") + dt.Rows(k).Item("OpeningCredit")
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            dt.Clear()
            depthchang = depthchang - 1
        Next
```

This code gives me my required output.